# How to set collapse on all other divs when one div is open?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have seen many questions but none are similar to my case. I have bootstrap `collapse and show` for a few `div contents`. The div `content` shows when title is clicked. I want to close all other `div contents` when I click another content's `title`.

The color of the `title` div is gray and should change to white when its content shows. Once the content is collapsed, `title div` color should back to gray.

Here's my code:

```js
 

 function collapse (e, id, collapasibleName) {
 var toggleColor = document.getElementById(id);
 var collapsibles = document.getElementById(collapasibleName);
 if(collapsibles.className == 'home__questions-content collapse' || collapsibles.className == 'home__questions-content collapsed') 
 {
  alert("Sdfsdfdsf")
  toggleColor.classList.remove('home__questions-title-show'); 
 }

 if(collapsibles.className == 'home__questions-content collapse show') {
  alert("in show")
  toggleColor.classList.add('home__questions-title-show'); 
 }
}
```

```css
.home__more-questions-content {
 padding-right: 40px;
 padding-left:40px;
 padding-bottom: 20px;
 background-color: $white-color;
 position:relative;
 max-width: 1080px;
 margin: auto;
}
 
.home__questions-content-tile {
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 border:1px solid #eee; 
}

.home__questions-content-title {
 padding:20px;
 background-color: #000
 cursor: pointer;
}

.home__questions-content {
 padding-top: 0;
 padding-right:20px;
 padding-left:20px;
 padding-bottom:20px;
}

.home__questions-title-show { background-color: #fff; }

.collapse {
  display:none;
}

.collapse.show {
 display: block;
}
  
.collapsing {
 position: relative;
 height: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
 transition: height 0.35s ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="home__more-questions-content"  id="accordion">
  <div class="home__questions-content-tile"> 
      <div class="home__questions-content-title" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsible-one" data-parent="#accordion" id="collapse-one" onclick="collapse(event, this.id,'collapsible-one');">
        <h2>
       // title 1 here
        </h2>
    </div>
       <div class="home__questions-content collapse" id="collapsible-one"> 
        //title 1's content here
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="home__questions-content-tile"> 
    <div class="home__questions-content-title" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsible-two" data-parent="#accordion" id="collapse-two" onclick="collapse(event, this.id,'collapsible-two');">
        <h2>
        //title 2
        </h2>
    </div>
    <div class="home__questions-content collapse" id="collapsible-two"> 

                   //title 2's content here
        </div>
    </div>
     <div class="home__questions-content-tile"> 
        <div class="home__questions-content-title" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsible-three" data-parent="#accordion" id="collapse-three" onclick="collapse(event, this.id, 'collapsible-three');">
      <h2>
        //title 3
       </h2>
    </div>
    <div class="home__questions-content collapse" id="collapsible-three"> 
             // title 3's content here
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: First things first: you pass `string`s as third parameter of your `collapse` function. They don't have a `className` property. You want to pass a DOM element (or rework your function).

Comment: yes, i fixed that.

Comment: The idea is you set an event listener to the container div which wraps all the collapsable divs. When a title is clicked, you collapse all the divs in the event handler (they will be bubbled to the listener), and then open the event.target that is the title clicked. I think you can figure that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code, explanation is in the comment of the question.

Add new code

```
if (e.target.parentNode.classList.contains('active')) {
  e.target.parentNode.classList.remove('active')
  return
}
```

If current block is opened, then close it and return from further processing.

```js
  const container = document.querySelector('.container')
  container.addEventListener('click', e => {
    if (e.target.parentNode.classList.contains('active')) {
      e.target.parentNode.classList.remove('active')
      return
    }
    const collapsable = document.querySelectorAll('.item')
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(collapsable, el => {
      el.classList.remove('active')
    })
    e.target.parentNode.classList.add('active')
  })
```

```css
  .container {
    width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    color:darkslategrey;
  }
  .item {
    margin: 10px 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #666;
    padding: 5px 10px;
  }

  .item.active h3 {
    color:aquamarine;
  }

  p {
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: height .5s ease;
    height: 0px;
  }

  .item.active p {
    height: 80px;
  }
```

```html
  <div class="container">
    <div class="item active">
      <h3>I am a title</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni minus neque nisi, rem doloribus unde quisquam, similique distinctio voluptate mollitia praesentium quo ut magnam ducimus nemo vitae soluta impedit harum?</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <h3>I am a title</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni minus neque nisi, rem doloribus unde quisquam, similique distinctio voluptate mollitia praesentium quo ut magnam ducimus nemo vitae soluta impedit harum?</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <h3>I am a title</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni minus neque nisi, rem doloribus unde quisquam, similique distinctio voluptate mollitia praesentium quo ut magnam ducimus nemo vitae soluta impedit harum?</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: thank you so much. I tried `console` and `alert` in both functions. The code is not going inside `Array.prototype.forEach.call`. Is this because I am using **pure javascript**? How can I allow the code to go into this function? And in my case, I do not need any of them to be active initially. They become active only after a click.

Comment: is there any way around this?

Comment: @AdityaPattani I am not sure what do you mean, what do you mean `console` and `alert` and `Array.prototype.forEach.call`

Comment: i solved that issue. But why is the collapsible not opening on first click?

Comment: what happens is it makes the class item active but does not display the content on first click. IT takes 3-4 clicks to display the content

Comment: @AdityaPattani, plz post the code, or I can not figure that out.

Comment: I had all the `p` and `h2` tags wrapped in `div` so i couldn't get the code to work smoothly. Then i removed the `div` tags and did exactly the way you had set the code and it worked.  why cant `div` elements work the same as  `h2` and `p`   tags?

Comment: I can collapse the content of the `active` title, by clicking on another title. If I click on the active `title` itself, how can i collapse its content? I tried using `toggle()` but that didnt work out well. For ex: if `title 1` is `active` and i click on `title 2`, `title 1's` content will collapse. That is perfect. But now, if `title 1` is `active` and i click on it, its content will not collapse until I click on `title 2`.

Comment: @AdityaPattani, The `div` problem is probably that you did not choose the right css selector in jQuery, so after remove div, your code works. The origin answer did not support self close, I added some new lines, now before any processing in your handlers, check if the current is opened already, then close it and quit the handlers, you can see my answer edited.